# Problems with .ccb file for sprite in SpriteBuilder

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am trying to understand SpriteBuilder. I made a new file `hero.ccb` for sprite and set it's sprite frame to the image I need. When I go back to the MainScene and drag `hero.ccb` from the left menu,there is just a CCBFile without anything(no sprite image). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you didn't save the hero.ccb. Choose File -> Save All or simply Publish the project to have SpriteBuilder update all references.